# Join zero-terminated string with ;

Tags: shell

I have output from `$(realpath -z foo bar)`, which I need to join with a `;` into a string to pass it to CMake.
How could I do this using no Bash specific methods?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by *no Bash specific* methods. In most shells you can do:

```
$ realpath -z foo bar | tr '\0' ';' | sed 's,;$,,'.
```

Add `&& echo` at the end if you want a newline.